# Cannot get characters consecutively in a loop

Tags: c, loops, character

This is just a simple program, that tries to get characters until '0' is entered. But, when i execute this on Code::Blocks 17.12, the terminal always seems to get two characters as input before printing the entered character.

```
char temp;
do  {
     printf("Enter character: ");
     scanf("%c ",&temp);
     printf("Character entered: [%c]\n",temp);
}while(temp!='0');
```

The result i got was

```
Enter character: a
b
Character entered: [a]
Enter character: c
Character entered: [b]
Enter character: d
Character entered: [c]
Enter character: e
Character entered: [d]
Enter character: 0
Character entered: [e]
Enter character: 0
Character entered: [0]
```

My expected result was

```
Enter character: a
Character entered: [a]
Enter character: b
Character entered: [b]
Enter character: c
Character entered: [c]
Enter character: c
Character entered: [c]
Enter character: 0
Character entered: [0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you ask `scanf` to skip *trailing* white-space in your format string. For `scanf` to know when and where the trailing white-space ends, there must be some input that isn't a white-space.

The solution is to skip *leading* white-space with the format string `" %c"`.

Comment: I have another doubt, i tried scanf("%c\n",&temp); How come that didn't work?

Comment: @suryathiags For `scanf`, any white-space character in the format string is equal, doesn't matter if it's a tab (`'\t'`) or space (`' '`) or newline (`'\n'`). So the trailing newline is no different from what you already had.

Comment: One last question. I tried the original code in Gfg ide and it worked. The input was ```a b c d e 0``` . From what i can think , it worked because, it was the same case , but then since there is nothing after the last 0, it  must've accepted 0 as input. Am i correct to some extent?

Comment: @suryathiags For automated systems, the input is usually piped to the program. And when the input is over then reading from the pipe will lead to end-of-file (`EOF`). That's probably what happened there.